# If count > 0, then install Google Chrome

Tags: powershell

I created a small script which checks if the below registry key exists. If it exists, the count is "1". I would like that if the count is higher than 0, it installs Google Chrome on the C: Drive.

```
$hits = Get-ChildItem -Path "Registry::HKEY_USERS\*\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\Google Chrome" 
Write-Host $hits.count
```

I have another Powershell script that installs Chrome (via GPO):

```
MsiExec.exe /i "\\FileShare\NETLOGON\googlechromestandaloneenterprise64.msi" /qn ALLUSERS=1
```

Is it possible to combine these 2 scripts in one way?
So if the count of the first script is higher than 0, it should install Chrome with the second script?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: it's a quite basic case of `IF-THEN`. What is, exactly, the problem?

Answer (score 2):

You can use get-package to detect the install in powershell 5.1:

```
If (!(get-package 'Google Chrome' -ea 0)) {
  install-package \\FileShare\NETLOGON\googlechromestandaloneenterprise64.msi
}
```

Comment: LOL, I spent like a couple minutes wondering what kind of comparison `-ea 0` was before realizing it was the short form of `-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue`

Answer (score 1):

You can run the following:

```
$hits = Get-ChildItem -Path "Registry::HKEY_USERS\*\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\Google Chrome"

if ($hits -gt 0) {
    MsiExec.exe /i "\\FileShare\NETLOGON\googlechromestandaloneenterprise64.msi" /qn ALLUSERS=1
}
```

To check the registry and then, run the installation.

Comment: Unless there is a need later for the value of `$hits`, I'd argue `Test-Path` is better

Comment: Agree with your commend @sirtao!

Comment: There is no need later for the value of $hits.
How would I have to implement the Test-Path? Sorry, I am new to Powershell.

Comment: `Test-Path` returns a boolean depending if the Path exists or not.   In this specific case, it returns `$true` if it finds AT LEAST one result.   To implement it you'd only have to replace `Get-ChildItem` with it and test `$hits` directly (so: `if($hits)`). Or even test it directly: `if(Test-Path -Path "yaddayadday)`. But js2010 's aolution might be better. I'll elaborate on it.

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks to @js2010

```
# if Get-Packege does NOT find Chrome installed, suppress the error.
# Failing means it returns $Null which is "-Not $true"
if(-not (Get-Package -name 'Google Chrome' -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue)) {
    install-package \\FileShare\NETLOGON\googlechromestandaloneenterprise64.msi 
}
```